# Radio buttons are scrolling with background, how to fix this?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I've got a problem with the radio buttons.
I am trying to fix the radio buttons on the background just like the other elements.
But now they are scrolling with the background when I am making the page smaller.
Can you please help me?
Thanks in advance!
For example:

[image: Screenshot]

```css
label[class=number]::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section) " " ;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

label[class=number] {
 display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 345px;
}

#bestellen input[type=number], #bestellen input[type=text], select {
 width: 40px;
    margin-left: 102%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -7%;
    border-color: skyblue;
    border-style: double;
}

input[type=range] {
    width: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 102%;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-top: -5%;
    display: block;
}

small {
 display: block;
    margin-left: 420px;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
}
```

```html
<form id="bestellen" action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi">
        <label class="number" id="David_Vann">David Vann - Aquarium: <input size="3" name="David_Vann" type="number" min="1"></label><small> Max. 10 exemplaren</small>
        <label class="number" id="Robert_Seethaler">Robert Seethaler - Een heel leven: <input size="3" name="Robert_Seethaler" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{2}"></label><small> Max. 99 exemplaren</small>
        <label id="Paula" class="number">Paula Hawkins - Het meisje in de trein: <input name="Paula_Hawkins" type="range" min="0" max="15" step="5" list="Paula_Hawkins"></label><small>Bestel 0, 5, 10 of 15 exemplaren</small>
          <datalist id="Paula_Hawkins">
            <option value="0">
            <option value="5">
            <option value="10">
            <option value="15">
         </datalist>
        <label class="number" id="Ernest_van_der_kwast">Ernest van der Kwast - De ijsmakers: </label>
        <label id="ernest"> <input type="radio" name="Ernest van der kwast" value="1">1</label>
        <label id="ernest"> <input type="radio" name="Ernest van der kwast" value="10">10</label>
        <label id="ernest"> <input type="radio" name="Ernest van der kwast" value="20">20</label><br>
        <label class="number" id="Bert_natter">Bert Natter - Remington: 
            <select name="Bert Natter"> 
              <option value="geen">geen</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
             </select>
         </label>
   </form>
```

Comment: Not causing this problem, but IDs should be unique to the document. In other words, you can't repeat `<label id="ernest">` three times.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set radio button after label then update code and move input radio after label tag

```
<label id="ernest"> 1<input type="radio" name="Ernest van der kwast" value="1"></label>
<label id="ernest"> 10<input type="radio" name="Ernest van der kwast" value="10"></label>
<label id="ernest"> 20<input type="radio" name="Ernest van der kwast" value="20"></label><br>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the problem I have is that when i make the page smaller the radio buttons will scroll together with the background. And they have to be fixed just like the other elements. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: you want to make it responvise?

Answer (score 0):

```css
label[class=number]::before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section) " " ;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

label[class=number] {
 display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 345px;
}

#bestellen input[type=number], #bestellen input[type=text], select {
 width: 40px;
    margin-left: 102%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -7%;
    border-color: skyblue;
    border-style: double;
}

input[type=range] {
    width: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 102%;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-top: -5%;
    display: block;
}

small {
 display: block;
    margin-left: 420px;
    margin-top: -1.5%;
}
```

```html
<form id="bestellen" action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi">
        <label class="number" id="David_Vann">David Vann - Aquarium: <input size="3" name="David_Vann" type="number" min="1"></label><small> Max. 10 exemplaren</small>
        <label class="number" id="Robert_Seethaler">Robert Seethaler - Een heel leven: <input size="3" name="Robert_Seethaler" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{2}"></label><small> Max. 99 exemplaren</small>
        
        <label id="Paula" class="number">Paula Hawkins - Het meisje in de trein: <input name="Paula_Hawkins" type="range" min="0" max="15" step="5" list="Paula_Hawkins"></label><small>Bestel 0, 5, 10 of 15 exemplaren</small>
          <datalist id="Paula_Hawkins">
            <option value="0">
            <option value="5">
            <option value="10">
            <option value="15">
         </datalist>
         <br>
         
         
        <label class="number" id="Ernest_van_der_kwast">Ernest van der Kwast - De ijsmakers: </label>
        
        1<label id="ernest"> <input type="radio" name="Ernest van der kwast" value="1"></label>
        10<label id="ernest"> <input type="radio" name="Ernest van der kwast" value="10"></label>
        20<label id="ernest"> <input type="radio" name="Ernest van der kwast" value="20"></label><br>
        
        
        <label class="number" id="Bert_natter">Bert Natter - Remington: 
            <select name="Bert Natter"> 
              <option value="geen">geen</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
             </select>
         </label>
   </form>
```

Comment: Code blocks on their own are not usually useful answers, and are more likely to attract downvotes. Please explain what the solution you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question.

Comment: @Jolanda You want to resposive radio button i think ?? right

Comment: @Jolanda try to use class="radio-inline"  in label  and include bootstrap css in header ..

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, when i am scrolling it shows the radio buttons on the next line like this: http://i32.photobucket.com/albums/d6/ganster321/Schermafbeelding%202017-06-05%20om%2019.05.15_1.png, but i want it to be on that same line when i make the page smaller.

Comment: @Jolanda my comment was to the answerer. It's not clear what they changed and therefore this answer is less useful than it could be.